# How to access an object that could have several data types in an Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider having a TypeScript variable which can have one of several data types. The data types have different properties:

```
let individual: Human | Dog;

export interface Human {
  public hairColor: string;
}

export interface Dog {
  public coatColor: string;
}
```

Now, in my Angular template code I try to access the object property `individual.coatColor`. In IntelliJ, the property "coatColor" will not be accepted, presumably because `individual` could also be a human that would not have a property `coatColor` at all.

So how can I still access an object's property even if it only exists on one of several applicable data types? In the component code, I could use an explicit conversion (`(individual as Dog).coatColor`) or [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), but what about an Angular template code?

Comment: AFAIK there is unfortunatly no solution to this in the HTML templates.
One 'workaround' to get rid of the error message is to also declare the type 'any', so in your case "let individual: Human | Dog | any".

Answer (score 2):

My usual answer to questions like this that amount to "how do I do something complex in an Angular template?" is....don't. Keep the template simple. Do it in Typescript (in your component) instead.

The template language looks like Typescript / JavaScript, but isn't, and is much less capable.

If you want a formatted 'individual' for display, the write a Typescript method in your component (potentially with the use of type guards) that formats it, and then call that method from the template.